# Hosting a video viewing website

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, hosting

I want to put a simple video viewing site where i will be uploading some local dramas for viewers to go and watch, just like youtube. I am starting with some few videos of around 20GB in size and is considering joomla for developement.

My problem is the hosting. Please where should i host the videos? cloud hostind, shared, dedicated servers? if  cloud can i go with amazon and how ? Also i realized video streaming site like vimeo have a plus package that looks good , i am nt sure if can host my vids there also. Please need recommendations and advice.

While advicing, please bear in mind its new site and therefore lil bandwidth. The storage is not much for a start. Also price and efficiency. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are much better off hosting your videos on YouTube or Vimeo or other such service and then use your website as a portal/gateway to find a view those videos. For a lot of reasons, but especially if you are on a budget and/or concerned about bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you sir but , i want the video to display only on my site and no where else. if i take it to youtube, people can watch on youtube and will not have control over my video. Moreover , we want a medium that will allow us to embed an ad incase of one.

Comment: You can do this with Vimeo Pro, which costs some $160 per year.

Answer (score 0):

Since youtube and vimeo are all free services, which u can always use, your next best bet will be paid/trial services.

Livestream is a good service, and you could do on demand as well as live broadcast. You could also find a lot more streaming services provider / CDN. Brighcove is also good.

For paid services (CDN/Hosting providers) may charge you per GB basis. The more GB you commit, the less you pay for per GB (maybe like 50cents per GB or even cheaper).

Advantages for CDN/Paid services, will be you have more control of your videos, restrict/charge money, etc...

You could use JWPlayer (or any similar player) to embed your video in your site.

Hope this helps.